# Meaning of 「兵法」

Tags: translation

I have a question about the meaning of 兵法 in the following passage. If I'm understanding correctly in the first sentence it means 「[剣術・柔術などの武術](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%85%B5%E6%B3%95-129027#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88)」. But what about the last one? Does 双厳 says something like "there is 'tactics' like this" referring to the sentence before, 「変移抜刀には変移抜刀を・・・・・」, in this case, I think the meaning would be closer to 「用兵や戦闘の方法」. Or does he refers to the next sentence, where stand in the stance for 変移抜刀落水?

> 双厳「つまり、抜刀に対して天の構えなどという単純な兵法では貴様に勝つ事などできん」
>
> 舞「ならどうする」
>
> ・・・・・(Some lines are skipped)
>
> 双厳「変移抜刀には変移抜刀を・・・・・」
>
> 双厳「**こういう兵法**もありなんじゃないか」
>
> 双厳は鞘に入ったまま剣を地の構えに構える。
>
> それは、まさに秘太刀”変移抜刀落水”であった。

Comment: I guess, because he is saying こういう, it is refering to the 変移抜刀落水 stance. If not, it would probably be そういう.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, こういう兵法 means 変移抜刀落水.

Another but same meaning,

こういう手もありなんじゃないか。

こういうやり方もありなんじゃないか。

But you should be aware. This conversation about '武道'. Therefore you can use '兵法'.　If things are not relevant with 武道, using '兵法' is wrong.